# Rails params permit I am getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am trying to create a form where I am putting the hidden value which is generating an array which is like :

```
"comment"=>{"comment"=>"sss", "feed_id"=>"354"}, "commit"=>"Comment"}
```

But when I am trying to use in controller with permit it produce an error my controller query is like this :

```
@feeds= Feed.find(params["comment"]["feed_id"])
```

This @feeds work great but when I am trying to use this with permit params it is showing error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: feed):
```

To permit I am using this query :

```
 def feed_params

      #params.require(:feed).permit(comment: :feed_id)
      params.require(:feed).permit(comment: [ :feed_id, :comment ])
      #params[:market_place]
    end
```

When I am adding it here in my controller like this :

```
@feeds= Feed.find(feed_params)
```

I am getting this error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: feed):
```

And this is my form :

```
 <%= form_for(@comment,:remote  => true)  do |f|  %>


<%= f.text_area :comment,  class:"form-control  post required" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :feed_id, {:value => @feed} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your `feed_params` to `require(:feed)`, then Rails will expect `params` to have a `"feed"` key and value, which does not. Your form is for *comments*, so you actually define a `comment_params` method. Define it like this:

```
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:comment, :feed_id)
end
```

And then find your Feed like this:

```
@feeds= Feed.find(comment_params["feed_id"])
```

And you should be all set.